# Multiple time-series Forecasting

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, google-colaboratory, prophet

I'm trying to make a forecast for multiple time-series, for this purpose I have a Prophet function to make a prediction on a certain date in future.
When I try using multiprocessing it shows me this: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
I noticed that it's because I'm not making a `"future_dataframe(periods=…)"`
How can I make it work?
My goal is to count a difference in % between two dates, separated by one month, or 2 months, etc. With for-loop I can count an average (in groups) difference in % between two dates. I'm curious, is it possible to do it using multiprocessing

```
def train_and_forecast(group):
  prevmonth=datetime.date(2021, 9, 1)
  timedelta=relativedelta(months=6)
  # Initiate the model
  m = Prophet(weekly_seasonality=False, yearly_seasonality=False, changepoint_range=0.8,changepoint_prior_scale=0.8)
  if group.shape[0] > 2:
  # Fit the model
    m.fit(group)
    # Make predictions
    future_date = pd.DataFrame(prevmonth+timedelta)
    #future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=30)
    global forecast
    forecast = m.predict(future_date)[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']]
    #forecast = m.predict(future)[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']]
    forecast['ticker'] = group['ticker'].iloc[0]

  # Return the forecasted results
  return forecast[['ds', 'ticker', 'yhat', 'yhat_upper', 'yhat_lower']], m
```

```
#def MultiProcessing(prev):
  
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
  # Process bar
from tqdm import tqdm
  # Start time
start_time = time()# Get time series data for each ticker and save in a list
series = [groups_by_ticker.get_group(ticker) for ticker in ticker_list]# Create a pool process with the number of worker processes being the number of CPUs
  #multiprocess_forecast=pd.DataFrame()
p = Pool(cpu_count())# Make predictions for each ticker and save the results to a list
timedelta=relativedelta(months=6)
predictions = list(tqdm(p.imap(train_and_forecast, series), total=len(series))) #Terminate the pool process
  # DATE
  p.close()# Tell the pool to wait till all the jobs are finished before exit
p.join()# Concatenate results
  #multiprocess_forecast.append(predictions) #= pd.concat(predictions)# Get the time used for the forecast
testtime=time()-start_time
print(testtime)
```

Comment: Please include code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Edit your post, please and replace images of code with text in a code block ``` ````

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `future_date = pd.DataFrame(prevmonth+timedelta)` create a future dataframe using the `make_future_dataframe()` function [docs](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html) in Prophet like:

```
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=1, freq='M')
```

Comment: If I do it this way, then last row in time series is: 7 2020-12-23       
and prediction is: 8 2020-12-31, but I need a prediction for 2021-01-23, or 2021-02-23 or smth like that

Comment: My goal is to count a difference in % between two dates, separated by one month, or 2 months, etc.  With for-loop I can count an average (in groups) difference in % between two dates. I'm curious, is it possible to do it using multiprocessing
I already noticed that multiprocessing takes almost the same amount of time as for-loop, so may be it's not worth it.